# How to get around recursive stack overflow?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

**EDIT: Just to clarify, the recursion is required as part of an assignment, so it must be recursive even though I know that's not the best way to do this problem**

I made a program that, in part, will search through an extremely large dictionary and compare a given list of words with each word in the dictionary and return a list of words that begin with the same two letters of the user-given word.

This works for small dictionaries but I just discovered that for dictionaries over a certain amount there is a stack limit for the recursions, so I get a stack overflow error.

My idea is to limit each recursion to 1000 recursions, then increment a counter for another 1000 and start again where the recursive method last left off and then end again at 2000, then so on until the end of the dictionary.

Is this the best way to do it? And if so, does anyone have any ideas how? I'm having a really hard time implementing this idea!

(**edit:** If it's not the best way, does anyone have any ideas of how to do it more effectively?)

Here is the code I have so far, the 1000 recursions idea is barely implemented here because I've deleted some of the code I tried in the past already but honestly it was about as helpful as what I have here.

the call:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < givenWords.size(); i++){
        int thousand = 1000;
        Dictionary.prefix(givenWords.get(i), theDictionary, 0, thousand);
        thousand = thousand + 1000;
    }
```

and the prefix method:

```
  public static void prefix (String origWord, List<String> theDictionary, int wordCounter, int thousand){

    if(wordCounter < thousand){ 
            // if the words don't match recurse through this same method in order to move on to the next word
        if (wordCounter < theDictionary.size()){   
          if ( origWord.charAt(0) != theDictionary.get(wordCounter).charAt(0) || origWord.length() != theDictionary.get(wordCounter).length()){
              prefix(origWord, theDictionary, wordCounter+1, thousand+1);

          }

          // if the words first letter and size match, send the word to prefixLetterChecker to check for the rest of the prefix.
          else{
              prefixLetterChecker(origWord, theDictionary.get(wordCounter), 1);
              prefix(origWord, theDictionary, wordCounter+1, thousand+1);
          }
        }
    }
    else return;
     }
```

**edit for clarification:**

The dictionary is a sorted large dictionary with only one word per line, lowercase

the "given word" is actually one out of a list, in the program, the user inputs a string between 2-10 characters, letters only no spaces etc. The program creates a list of all possible permutations of this string, then goes through an array of those permutations and for each permutation returns another list of words beginning with the first two letters of the given word.

If as the program is going through it, any letter up to the first two letters doesn't match, the program moves on to the next given word.

Comment: The recursion is required as part of an assignment

Comment: Ahh. In that context, write it using a [*binary search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). This will decrease the depth from `n` to `lg(n)` and avoid the stack overflow. The only requirement is the dictionary is sorted. Since the matching letters can "split" a i/2 division you will need to account for the back-out case to find the first/last word also matching.

Comment: Hmmm okay I'll look into binary searches, the dictionaries are sorted

Comment: thank you! any chance you have good resources for implementing binary searches?

Comment: Also instead of just binary (which would work), the fan-out could be for each letter (e.g a..z). I added a link to my previous comment to Wikipedia.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Is what you call "a given list of words" the same thing as what you call "an extremely large dictionary"?  Or are the given list and the dictionary different?  And is the "user-given word" something else even? Thanks.

Comment: What is your base case?  That is, when do you *stop* recursing?

Comment: I will edit with those clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a nice assignment. Let's make some assumptions....

1. 26 letters in the alphabet, all words are in those letters.
2. no single word is more than.... 1000 or so characters long.

Create a class, call it 'Node', looks something like:

```
private static class Node {
    Node[] children = new Node[26];
    boolean isWord = false;
}
```

Now, create a tree using this node class. The root of this tree is:

```
private final Node root = new Node ();
```

Then, first word in the dictionary is the word 'a'. We add it to the tree. Note that 'a' is letter 0.

So, we 'recurse' in to the tree:

```
private static final int indexOf(char c) {
    return c - 'a';
}

private final Node getNodeForChars(Node node, char[] chars, int pos) {
    if (pos == chars.length) {
        return this;
    }
    Node n = children[indexOf(chars[pos])];
    if (n == null) {
        n = new Node();
        children[indexOf(chars[pos])] = n;
    }
    return getNodeForChars(n, chars, pos + 1);
}
```

So, with that, you can simply do:

```
Node wordNode = getNodeForChars(root, word.toCharArray(), 0);
wordNode.isWord = true;
```

So, you can create a tree of words..... Now, if you need to find all words starting with a given sequence of letters (the `prefix`), you can do:

```
Node wordNode = getNodeForChars(root, prefix.toCharArray(), 0);
```

Now, this node, if isWord is true, and all of its children that are not-null and isWord is true, are words with the prefix. You just have to rebuild the sequence. You may find it advantageous to store the actual word as part of the Node, instead of the boolean isWord flag. Your call.

The recursion depth will never be more than the longest word. The density of the data is 'fanned out' a lot. There are other ways to set up the Node that may be more (or less) efficient in terms of performance, or space. The idea though, is that you set up your data in a wide tree, and your search is thus very fast, and all the child nodes at any point have the same prefix as the parent (or, rather, the parent is the prefix).